# add a list of items to a recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, view

I'd like to add elements to a list of items displayed by a recycler view in Android.

So far in my code, when the list gets close to the end I fetch some more items and append the list of new items to the current list that is displayed. I then call notifyDataSetChanged() but I get the following error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView...
```

How could I update the list to show while having the recycler stay on the item it is currently showing?

Here's my code:

```
 private class StatusRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StatusRecyclerHolder> {
    private List<Status> statues;
    private int size;


    private final int LOAD_POSITION = 3;


    public StatusRecyclerAdapter() {
         statues = feed.getStatuses();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public StatusRecyclerHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        return new StatusRecyclerHolder(layoutInflater, viewGroup);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull StatusRecyclerHolder statusRecyclerHolder, int i) {
        statusRecyclerHolder.bind(statues.get(i));
        if(size - i == LOAD_POSITION){
            getContentNextPage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        size = 0;
        if(statues == null){
            Log.i(TAG, "List of status null" );
        }
        else{
            size = statues.size();
        }

        return size;
    }

    private void getContentNextPage(){
        this.statues = Feed.getNextPage();
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you show you code?

Comment: it seems like you have something wrong with the code you gave, there is closing bracked after this.statues = Feed.getNextPage();, is it supposed to be there?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like what you code is trying to do is to update the recyclerview **WHILE** it is being updated which could potentially end up in an infinite loop some how. Can you call `getContentNextPage()` somewhere else and not in `onBindViewHolder(...)`, maybe call it from outside the `StatusRecyclerAdapter` class in your view maybe

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView will not allow you to call notifyDataSetChanged(); in the onBindViewHolder.that's why you are getting an exception. Try by removing notifyDataSetChanged it will work.

```
 private void getContentNextPage(){
        this.statues = Feed.getNextPage();
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();//REMOVE THIS LINE
    }
```